Borderlands 2 for PS3 has unbelievably low drop rates. Is something wrong?
I recently beat Normal mode for the first time. When I killed the Warrior, he did drop a couple of legendaries, and I was ecstatic!
However, as I moved into True Vault Hunter Mode (TVHM), and as I scour the internet and Youtube for tips and tricks to get Legendary weapons, I keep hearing that specific bosses/mini-bosses have a 10% drop rate that will yield a Legendary weapon. My problem is that this 10% drop rate isn't lining up with my own experiences in game, since I haven't gotten a single legendary since my first one, and I've killed over 200 bosses and mini-bosses. I know your first instinct is that I've just gotten unlucky, but not getting a single legendary after 200 bosses/mini-bosses killed seems like far more than just getting unlucky.
My fear is that I'm playing an out-of-date version of the game. My Playstation is NOT online. I'm playing the stock game, with no updates. I've heard that many updates have been made to the game, and I'm wondering if this also applies to drop rates. Could an update have changed a 1% drop rate to the now generally acknowledged and agreed upon 10% drop rate? Because that would certainly explain my troubles!
Any insight into what's going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to the site! I've edited your question to make it shorter. Your original answer is so long that I fear people will get lost in the weeds and completely miss what you're trying to get help with. I'm hoping this shorter version will make it easier for people to understand what you're asking. Also, if you know the exact build version of Borderlands 2 you're playing on, that would be really helpful too.

Short Version: I believe that 10% drop rates you're seeing online are referring to the drop rates for very specific items from very specific bosses. I also believe this only applies to the newest version of the game, which you don't have. For you, the drop rate for legendary items is normally only 0.009%.
Long Version: I've been doing some research online, and I believe I understand why you're experiencing such low drop rates for legendary items.
First off, according to this Reddit thread, the drop rate in Borderlands 2 for Legendary items is notoriously low. One poster even says the following:

Bl2 drop rates have always been pretty low. I usually only get 1 or 2 random legendaries per playthrough.

This seems to line-up with your own experiences, where you only got a single legendry across your first playthrough.
Next up are some posts from Gearbox, starting with this one from 2013. According to this post, the drop rate for legendaries is 0.009% (1 in 10,000). This is far, far lower than the 10% value you've seen online, but it does better align with your own experiences. Additionally, a 2015 post from Gearbox states that they tripled the drop rate for legendary items with a patch, which if you're not online, you likely don't have (although that's still only a drop rate of 0.027%).
I also stumbled across the site Lootlemon. From what I can tell, this site has drop rate information for all loot across the Borderlands series. When searching across this site, I  am finding some Legendary weapons with your referenced 10% drop rate, but that's only true for very specific bosses. For example, the Hornet appears to have a 10% drop rate, but only from the Knuckle Dragger boss.
Finally, there's this blog post which does reference that 0.009% drop rate from that first Gearbox post. However, it also talks about how some legendary weapons have designated drop sources which are closer 3.33% in the launch version, and 10% in the latest version.
My takeaway from all of this is that for your version of the game, the default drop rate for legendary items is 0.009%. There are very specific enemies which have a much higher drop rate for very specific legendary items, but that most bosses still only have that 0.009% drop rate for legendary items.

Holy smokes, thank you so, so much for that timely and in-depth response, despite the information being terribly bad news for me (I mentioned how I've 're-fallen' back in love with the game, especially with the prospect of Legendaries!). The number you have provided seem to correspond with my experience, so I have to assume that you are correct with the 0.009% legendary droprate that you provided. I guess my only options are to set up a wifi router and go online for the updates, or live with the fact that I'm going to have to grind the game at the highest level w/o legendary guns. Thx again!!

@Fenrisulv987 indeed, BL2 is far more stingy than BL3, but IMO on average the legendaries are better (BL3 has a lot of unique-but-not-good legendaries). And it is possible to actually get a “world drop” legendary from a Skag pile, or even a pearlescent which drop at an even lower rate (assuming you have the UVHM DLC)

@Fenrisulv987 I second the point raised by fyrepenguin. On average, BL2 gives you far far fewer legendary drops than BL3, but essentially all the legendaries in BL2 are useful (even if only for a handful of builds). In comparison, BL3 gives you a lot of legendary drops, but it has quite a few that are exceptionally difficult to use effectively or are little more than a purple with a wad of extra stats tacked on.

Thank you so much for your engagement, I appreciate it very much! Everything that has been said corroborates my suspicions, and everything else has been useful. 0o0o0 I can't tell you what I'd give for an Unkempt Harold, Badaboom, Shredifier, Hellfire, Lyuda, a Slagga, Norfleet, or Conference Call! But whatevs, let's see how lucky I get. Thx again, much love friends <3 <3

Thanks again for your responses, both of you! I must be tremendously lucky. I've done a bit of research, and I found an article published by Gearbox Production, and they verify the very thing you said: Rare Items: 1 in 100. Very rare: 1 in 1000. Extremely rare (e-tech) 1 in 10,000. Legendary: 1 in 100,000. So they comment of legendaries lying somewhere in the ballpark of 0.003% seems accurate. I must admit, I've been insanely lucky these last few days. I've found a Maggie, a Veruc, and a very nice legendary grenade mod.! Again, appreciate the fast and succinct replies. Cheers guys <3
